# Using Solr for indexing parameterized products

Tags: parameters, solr, indexing

We have to prepare new search functionality in our online store. I was wondering that we can use Solr. But I have some doubts about it. Every single product in our offer is parameterized. Actually a product is a bunch of parameters. It has a symbol, another symbol, producer, param, param, param. Everything we have about our products are their parameters. Some parameters are single value, some of them are multivalue.

Is it possible to index our products database and let our users filter by products parameters? This is very important for us, because our customers have already got used to search with advanced filtering. What about indexing these parameters in multiple languages?

Thanks for help!

Oh, and one more thing, can Solr use only part of a word for search? For example i have a product with symbom ABCDEFG. What if search ABC or DEFG? Can Solr handle such search?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you talking about solr facet? solr has a pretty good facet implementation. check this out:
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrFacetingOverview  .

For your second question, solr cannot handle that. You have to write your own lucene analyzer to split the word into parts during indexing. You can config your own analyzer in solr schema.xml. You need to check out what is a lucene analyzer first. It is not difficult to implement a analyzer. Try using trie or java treeset. Or you can find some robust analyzer implementation on google.

Comment: Faceting looks promising, thank you very much :). Especially helpful was this link -> [link]http://www.lucidimagination.com/Community/Hear-from-the-Experts/Articles/Faceted-Search-Solr. Shame there is no easy way for search in parts of words. I'll check the analyzers way. Thank you once again!

Comment: @CharlieQ you can achieve the searching of word parts using the EdgeNGramFilterFactory, please see http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory for more details.

Comment: @Paige thanks, this is helpful. Looks like it is derived from the lucene synonyms module

Answer (score 2):

You can either filter or facet by your distinct parameter fields (faceting allows browsing of content - I guess this is what you are looking for). Indexing in several languages is also not a problem - there is an existing supporting infrastructure - see SOLR language identification description. One thing to notice though - having lots of fields + many (millions and more) of records + many facets will consume a lot of memory and 'may' deteriorate performance.
Speaking about ABC or DEFG - why not using wildcard? ABC* or *DEFG. ABC* will work out of the box, *DEFG is more resource consuming and requires a special analyzer - it merely indexes your field into a special field with reverse order.

Hope this helps.